# Array of strings in C++: Extra characters printed

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I am having some trouble understanding this output for my code:

```
#define MAX 5

char pipeNames[MAX][1024];
string s1 = "\\\\.\\p\\p1";
string s2 = "\\\\.\\p\\p2";
int len1 = strlen(s1.c_str());
int len2 = strlen(s2.c_str());
memcpy((void*)pipeNames[0], (void*)s1.c_str(), len1);
memcpy((void*)pipeNames[1], (void*)s2.c_str(), len2);
cout<<pipeNames[0];
cout<<endl<<len1;
cout<<endl<<pipeNames[1];
cout<<endl<<len2;
```

Actual Output:

```
\\.\p\p1É┼é|
8
\\.\p\p2
8
```

Expected Output:

```
\\.\p\p1
8
\\.\p\p2
8
```

Why are the extra characters being printed at the end of pipeNames[0]. I am using string::c_str() which automatically appends null character, so why the error?

Comment: You're not including that null char in the memcpy...

Comment: In this case why not use strcpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not copying the null char. strlen does not count the null char. Try this

```
memcpy(pipeNames[0], s1.c_str(), len1 + 1);
memcpy(pipeNames[1], s2.c_str(), len2 + 1);
```

No need for your casts either. Casts are dangerous, because they can mask compiler errors so don't use them if you don't need them.

Comment: Or as Mark says, just use strcpy.

Comment: memcpy expects void* arguments. If I don't cast it explicitly, does implicit casting take place?

Answer (score 2):

This would be better

```
memcpy((void*)pipeNames[0], (void*)s1.c_str(), len1 + 1);
                                                      ^
memcpy((void*)pipeNames[1], (void*)s2.c_str(), len2 + 1);
                                                      ^
```

to ensure that you null terminate the copied string. Your initial array is not initialised, so the data in your array could be anything to start with - so if it was not a zero, your print functions will just carry on outputting until they DO find a null char.

Even better as one of your comments suggests, use `strcpy` instead